# Implementing Explicit free lists memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

As part of an assignment we have to implement a (basic) malloc function(we should somehow simulate dynamic memory allocation). I already implemented a solution based on implicit free list,but the problem is that i get a utilization of 50% and a throughput of 9% only(I have to get a 90% utilization+throughput). The problem with implicit free list is that it takes alot of time searching for free blocks. So i wanted to implement [explicit free list](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/course/cs61/mediawiki/images/b/b9/Lectures-malloc2.pdf) to see how much can the program improve. now the problem is that i have to keep track of next/prev pointers for free blocks. And since I can only use scalar variables and  cannot use any kind of data structures e.g:linked list,struct,.., i couldnt implement it. Can someone point out how can i keep track of (virtual) pointers in C?

thanks,

Comment: what do you mean "cannot use any kind of data structures e.g: linked list" but somehow you *can* have "next/prev pointers"? Something doesn't make sense.

Comment: @luserdroog so we are not allowed to use any kind of data structures. BUT the explicit free lists keep track of next/prev free blocks. in other words, explicit free lists is an algorithm, and i have to implement it.[explicity free lists](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/course/cs61/mediawiki/images/b/b9/Lectures-malloc2.pdf)

Comment: Ok. So you cannot "use (a pre-written) linked-list", because *this is* a linked-list. Right?

Comment: @luserdroog yes. I think i got it now, i just have to have a normal pointer with the an address(next or previous block) save in it ?

Comment: Added an answer. I'm in favor of structs.

Answer (score 0):

From the images in the slides (linked in the comments), I think you're expected to store the links as integer offsets.

In C, this really is best described as a struct.

```
struct alloc_cell {
    int size;
    int forward;
    int back;
    int data[];
};
```

Now, he also has the size repeated at the end, and that is much harder to describe with a struct. <del>It's not clear how necessary it is.</del> It's used for boundary coalescing.

---

*Edit: much later, considering comment.*

Even if you can't use structs in the code, you can still use them in the *pseudocode* to help organize your thinking. The struct fields, being all the same type, map naturally to an array 
represention which can be accessed by a pointer to the the first member/element.

```
struct alloc_cell {    // int *cell;
    int size;          // cell[0] // *cell
    int forward;       // cell[1]
    int back;          // cell[2]
    int data[];        // (cell+3)[...] // &cell[3]
};
```

You could even go so far as to give these offsets mnemonic names (but this may be considered *overkill* and unnecessary obfuscation).

```
enum { SIZE, FORWARD, BACK, DATA };

cell[SIZE];                   // alloc_cell.size
cell[FORWARD];                // alloc_cell.forward
cell[BACK];                   // alloc_cell.back
cell+DATA; // &cell[DATA]     // alloc_cell.data
```

Comment: well i thought of using struct, but as i said, structs are also not allowed. only scalar variables,